# Why is Pygame's KMOD_SHIFT unresolved and crashing my code?

Tags: python, pygame, unresolved-external

I wrote a simple program to test detection of the Shift key being pressed, I *think* it ought to work. The main issue seems to be the KMOD_SHIFT piece. I searched out shift detection using pygame and the test `pygame.key.get_mods() & KMOD_SHIFT` is what people said to use, and was in several code example as well. However, in MY code I get a warning that KMOD_SHIFT is an unresolved reference, and when I try to run the code, as soon as I press any key I get an error: "name KMOD_SHIFT is undefined".

Isn't Pygame supposed to define it? In other people's code examples of using this, they seem to be using it the same as me. What am I doing wrong here?

Still a major Python newbie - thanks for your guidance.

```
#! /usr/bin/python3

import pygame

pygame.init()
screen_width, screen_height = 800, 600
screen_color = [128, 128, 128]

game_display = pygame.display.set_mode((screen_width, screen_height))
pygame.display.set_caption('Coloriffic')
clock = pygame.time.Clock()

my_font = pygame.font.SysFont("monospace", 45)

crashed = False
shift_label = my_font.render("shift is NOT pressed", 1, (0, 0, 0))

while not crashed:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            crashed = True
        if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if pygame.key.get_mods() & KMOD_SHIFT: # the problem line
                shift_label = my_font.render("shift is pressed", 1, (0, 0, 0))
            else:
                shift_label = my_font.render("shift is NOT pressed", 1, (0, 0, 0))

    game_display.fill(screen_color)
    game_display.blit(shift_label, (100, 100))

    pygame.display.update()
    clock.tick(60)

pygame.quit()
quit()
```

Answer (score 2):

Nevermind, it seems that if I use `pygame.KMOD_SHIFT` all works fine. I don't know why other people didn't have to put the "pygame." in front, maybe they imported Pygame differently than I did.

False alarm, my apologies.

Comment: Many do `from pygame.constants import *` this imports all flags, keys, events etc.

Comment: If I did a `from pygame import *` would I be bale to use `for thing in event.get():` instead of `for thing in pygame.event.get():` ?

Comment: No, that's if you do `from pygame import *` which puts everything pygame into your namespace. This is however not recommended, as it can slow down your program.